# Error in tabular code generated from Excel2LaTeX

Tags: tables, errors, excel2latex

I used Excel2LaTeX to create a table in LaTeX and here is the code that gives me an error.

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \toprule
          &       & Start date & End date & Days spent \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}[12]{*}{\textbf{Background research}}} & Research which existing technologies exist for recommendation systems & 06/10/2011 & 10/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}[12]{*}{22}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Investigate the problems being face by the current recommender systems & 11/10/2011 & 15/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Learn what Semantic Web is and how the it is being implemented to solve problems & 16/10/2011 & 20/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Investigate how semantic web is being used for recommendation systems & 16/10/2011 & 20/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Read research papers on to find out more on work about music recommendation that has already been done in the past & 21/10/2011 & 27/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable: Write a literature survey to summarize research findings & 21/10/2011 & 28/10/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{}                  & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{\textbf{Analysis \& Design}}} & Create a structured list of requirements from the problem statement & 29/10/2011 & 04/11/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{6}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable produced: Create a structured list of requirements from the problem statement & 29/10/2011 & 04/11/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Begin prototyping and experimenting with Semantic Web & 05/11/2011 & 09/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{34}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable produced: A basic prototype of the recommender system & 05/11/2011 & 09/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{}                  & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{21}[42]{*}{\textbf{Implementation}}} & \textbf{Iteration 1  - Implementing and testing core functionality of the website} &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Let users register with the website & 10/12/2011 & 16/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{7}[14]{*}{34}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Simulate users listening to songs/albums & 10/12/2011 & 16/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Enable searching for music and playlists in the website & 17/12/2011 & 23/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Let users create playlists and add/remove songs to them & 24/12/2011 & 30/12/2011 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Users can integrate with Facebook and find friends that are also registered on the website & 31/12/2011 & 06/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Users can comment on a playlist and Like a playlist & 07/01/2012 & 13/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable produced: The first iteration of the website without a recommendation system & 10/12/2011 & 13/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{}          & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Iteration 2 - Implemented and testing core functionality of the algorithm} &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Integrate Semantic Web so that recommendation algorithm can be implemented & 14/01/2012 & 20/01/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}[10]{*}{27}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & The website shall allow users to get music recommendations based on the friend’s taste & 21/01/2012 & 03/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & The website shall allow users to get music recommendations based on the user’s taste & 21/01/2012 & 10/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverables produced: Algorithm for music recommendation & 14/01/2012 & 10/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Second iteration of the website with core functionality in place & 14/01/2012 & 10/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{r}{}          & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \textbf{Iteration 3 - Adding additional features (Could have's and Wont have's in the requirements)} &       &       &  \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Carry out the finishing touches of the website & 11/02/2012 & 24/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{13}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & View a feed which lets them find out what their friends are doing on the site through likes and comments & 11/02/2012 & 17/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Allow users to subscribe to a playlist & 18/02/2012 & 24/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable: Final version of the website with added features & 11/02/2012 & 24/02/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{}                  & \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[3]{*}{\textbf{Documentation}}} & Begin the final report & 25/02/2012 & 30/03/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}[3]{*}{34}} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Deliverable: Final report with explaining all stages of the software development cycle & 25/02/2012 & 30/03/2012 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

The error I'm getting is this

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> \endtemplate
l.692 \multicolumn{5}{r}{} &
\\
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: David's answer solved the problem but I don't have 6 columns in my excel sheet. [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/yek68o) here is the link to my excel sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 columns

```
{rrrrr}
```

but you have

```
\multicolumn{5}{r}{}                  & \\
```

so that's a 5 column span then & then an empty cell so six columns,

Easiest would be to add an extra r at the top so you have 6 columns declared.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug in `excel2latex`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/excel2latex/+bug/824923), which will be fixed in version 3.2 (currently under development). Visit https://code.launchpad.net/excel2latex for version updates.